# ¿Alguien sabe como leer un excel con PhpSpreadsheet en Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

estoy tratando de leer un archivo excel en **codeigniter** para guardarlo en una base de datos. Estuve buscando una libreria php para trabajar con excel y encontre **phpExcel** pero al ir al sitio me dice que esta deprecated y que ahora es **phpspreadsheet** y no logro encontrar algún ejemplo que muestre como utilizarlo.

Comment: En el repositorio dentro de la [carpeta `samples`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/tree/develop/samples) podes encontrar muchos ejemplos.

Comment: Revisa la documentación, empezado por [aquí (explican todo desde el inicio)](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) y luego por [aquí (explican procesos para leer/escribir)](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/)

Answer (score 2):

Por ser una librería que es bastante utilizada y actualizada constantemente recomiendo [PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). Aquí dejo un script básico desde su instalación hasta la apertura de una archivo excel.

Para la instalación basta con el siguiente comando:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Esto va a crear la carpeta `vendor` con la siguiente estructura

```
vendor
  |
  ├─ composer
  |
  └─ phpoffice
        |
        └─ phpspreadsheet
```

Una vez instalado la librería puede abrir un archivo en formato Xlsx de la siguiente forma

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $filename = "mi_archivo.xlsx";
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($filename);
try {

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Ocurrio un error al intentar abrir el archivo ' . $e;
}
```

Existe una serie de ejemplos que puede revisar [aquí](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/tree/develop/samples/Reader) espero que esto te de una luz para resolver